# How can I compute partial derivatives of a function depending on multiple parameters using "Deriv"

Tags: r, symbolic-math, derivative

I am trying to use the package [Deriv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Deriv/index.html), to compute symbolic derivatives of a function depending on one or two variables and a vector of parameters. However, i always obtain the error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Could not retrieve body of '[()'

I have tried:

```
test_fun <- function(x,y,par){x\*par[1]+y\*par[2]}  
Deriv(test_fun,"x",par=c(2,2))
```

which yields the above error. So does

```
par <- c(2,2)  
test_fun <- function(x,y,par){x\*par[1]+y\*par[2]}  
Deriv(test_fun,"x")
```

Obviously

```
test_fun <- function(x,y,par){x\*2+y\*2}  
Deriv(test_fun,"x")
```

works as intended, but is not what I want.

Reading the Documentation for the Deriv-package, it seems that directly passing additional arguments to the function is not supported. Is there any other way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: the last example on `?Deriv` does what you want

Comment: The last example deals with adding a custom derivation rule. I'm sorry but i don't see directly how this solves my question. Although i might be misunderstanding that example, as i don't fully understand the use of the second argument "y" in that construction. Could you add a minimal working example?

Comment: sorry maybe I misunderstood, but I was referring to the part about passing arguments to the function in turn being passed to `Deriv`.  In your case, that would be `Deriv(test_fun(par=c(2,2)), "x")`

Comment: @bunk This zields similiar problems as the answer suggested by Patrick. The output is apparently a `language` and i have no idea how to extract the relevant information, the outputis not a a function, and `as.numeric(Deriv(test_fun(par=c(2,2)), "x")` yields an error. Furthermore this Method only seems to work when inserting the parameters directly. `test_par <- c(2,2); Deriv(test_fun(par=test_par), "x")` fails, again producing `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Could not retrieve body of '[()'`

Comment: you can `eval` the result, but I agree it's not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer (9/16):

There's two options below for passing the parameters through `Deriv`. Also note that `Derive` will retain curly braces in the original function, so either define your functions without them or call `eval()` afterwards.

Option 1. Define within the call to `Deriv`

```
test_fun <- function(x,y,par){x*par[1]+y*par[2]}
eval(Deriv(test_fun(par=c(2,2)),'x'))
# [1] 2
```

Option 2. Define the parameter values in as a function.

```
test_fun <- function(x,y,par){x*par[1]+y*par[2]}
tpar <- function() c(2,2)
eval(Deriv(test_fun(par=tpar()), "x"))
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Breaking apart the paramater works, but seems very unelegant for functions depending on a large number of parameters. Your second sugestion looks promising, but theoutput occurs in a rather strange form.`as.numeric(Deriv(test_fun(x,y,c(2,2))))` yields `Error: 'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'` Any idea how to convert the output to something more practical? @PatrickB

Comment: OK, I figured it out. The `Deriv` function kept the curly braces around the function definition. I believe this will continue to be a limitation for functions which require more than one line to define, but I got it to work for your test_fun. See edit above.

Comment: I have also made some progress: One can also escape the curly braces by using `eval()`. This also works if the derivative still depends on `x`. Although i had to assign a value to x outside of the `eval()` Furthermore i discovered that you can insert the parameter using a function. So while `tpar<-c(2,2)` followed by `Deriv(test_fun(x,y,par=tpar),"x")` does not work, one can use `tpar <- function() c(2,2)` followed by `Deriv(test_fun(x,y,par=tpar()),"x")`. This seems really kludgey and i am not sure if this is intended behavior, but it works. Could you update your answer accordingly?